# Maxima: Linear fit on data

Tags: maxima

I am new in Maxima. I have a set of data, (x,y,error) and I want to fit a linear line on it. I found some examples in [example by maxima](http://web.csulb.edu/~woollett/#mbe) "Chapter 5: 2D Plots and Graphics using qdraw " but honestly I don't know how to download and use "qdraw" package.
anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

I see that `qdraw.mac` is linked from the page you mentioned. Maybe you can search for `qdraw.mac` on that page.

Maxima has some capability to work with linear regression models, but other packages which are specifically devoted to statistics might be more suitable. Have you tried R? (http://www.r-project.org)

Comment: Thank you Robert for your suggestion, I hear R for the first time. I hope I can understand it.